# JSF ajax listner not working for dropdown

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to add ajax for a dropdown and I have added the below code in my xhtml but the listner is not getting called once there is a change.

XHTML Code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu
                            value="#{loginBean.dropDownValue}" itemValue="#{dropDownValue}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="****select***" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.testDropDown}"/>
                             <f:ajax event="change" listner="#{loginBean.changeDropDownOne}" render="testDropDownTwoValue" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Method in the bean:

```
public List<SelectItem> changeDropDownOne() {
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$");
        String dp = getDropDownValue();
        if(dp != null) {
            System.out.println("**********************getTestDropDownTwo********************************"+dp);
            if(dp.equalsIgnoreCase("One")) {
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("One - One"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("One - Two"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("One - Three"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("One - Four"));
            } else if(dp.equalsIgnoreCase("Two")) {
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Two - One"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Two - Two"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Two - Three"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Two - Four"));
            }else if(dp.equalsIgnoreCase("Two")) {
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Three - One"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Three - Two"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Three - Three"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Three - Four"));
            }else {
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Four - One"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Four - Two"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Four - Three"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Four - Four"));
            }
        }
        return testDropDownTwo;
    }
```

Comment: First thing, `listner` should be `listener`...

Comment: did that. still not working.

Comment: Instead of `listener` in ajax tag try `valueChangeListener=#{loginBean.changeDropDownOne}"` directly in `<h:selectoneMenu>`.And there is such attribute as `itemValue` in `selectOneMenu`. And In your ajax listener it should be associated with `AjaxBehaviorEvent` in your `changedropdown` method.

Comment: Did you put your `<h:selectOneMenu>` inside a `<h:form>`?

Comment: How does the testDropDownTwoValue look like? Also add a global <h:messages /> and let it be ajax-rendered to be sure not to have any other errors blocking in validation phase.

Comment: @SRy: `valueChangeListener` is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)